# Word 2019: How to create a numbered list in a document of groups of 4 lines where each line is a paragraph just numbering the first line of each?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

On my walk to add captions to my photographs of paintings to post on my socials, I've pasted the information related to each (name of image, etc.) in a Word document of ten pages.
So every page has the following layout:
[image]

How to create a numbered list, adding the number to the first line of every group of four?
I've tried to find a feature in Word with no result. Another attempt has been to replace the paragraph character with the line break one, but it requires using Regular expressions in an advanced way to reach my final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A not intuitive answer is replacing ^p with ^l. Then replace ^l^l with ^p.
This will place each caption in a single paragraph.
Then I applied the List Number style.